# Check if validation failed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I would like to know when a validation failed by using this kind of code writing (I'm using [laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/))

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);
```

I know that I can use this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) { //Not okay }
```

But I would like to keep this way of validating by using `$this->validate` instead of using the `Validator` model.

So ... is it possible to use something like:

```
//This is not working btw

$test = $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);

if( $test )
{ //Ok }
else
{ //Not okay };
```

Comment: Try using FormRequests.

Comment: What is not working? Is it the validate method ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
$request->validate($rules);
```

or

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);
```

Then it returns the errors.

```
$test = $request->validate([
           'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
        ]);
```

and you need to check if there are no errors and then you can do what ever you want.

In your case you need to do it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return view('view_name');
} else {
    return view('view_name');
}
```

Comment: So it's not possible? I am forced to use the `Validator` method?

Comment: Yes. Not possible... if you want to redirect to some other page or do some custom stuff you need to use `Validator::make()` because it has that method `fails()`. Maybe you could create your own `fails()` method for `$request()->validate();`

Comment: use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;              don't forget to use this

Answer (score 2):

```
try{

$validateData = Validator::make($request->all(),
[
'name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255,
]);

if($validateData->fails()){

            return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'validation error',
            'errors' => $validateData->errors()
        ], 401);

$user = User::create([
'name'=>$request->name
]);

return response()->json([
      'message' => 'User created Successfuly',
      'user' => $user
    ],200);
}

catch(Throwable $th){
         return response()->json([
                    'message' => $th->getMessage()
                ], 500);
            }
```

Comment: The question was already answered, no need to reply 4 years later dude :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
```

then

```
    $validator =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        
    } else {
        # code...
    }
```

Comment: Validator is not imported from ```use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;```,rather it's ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;```

Answer (score -1):

Request validate will return true or false based on if your validation fails or passes.
You can use this to determine what what logic should happen if it returns false.

```
if($request->validate()){
   // logic for when validation passes
} else {
   // logic for when validation fails
{
```