# Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8
I want to make when the validation error , it will show the sweetalert or session message when error to the index page just like this

```
{{-- Flash data --}}
     @if(session()->has('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
       {{ session('success') }}
     <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
     </div>
```

but in my controller have an error here's in my controller

```
  public function verify(VerifyRequest $request)
          {
           // Verify using VerifyRequest
               $validated = array_merge($request->validated(), ['token' => Str::random(127)]);

                // the error in this line
            if($validated->validate()->fails()){
               return redirect(url()->previous() . '#verify-email')->withErrors($request)->withInput();
             }
             // end the error

       // create 
         Pengaduan::create($validated);
    // Setup the email message
        $data = [
            'content' => 'to create complaint please click the link below',
            'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/complaint/create/' . $validated['token'],
        ];
    // Send to email
    Mail::to($validated['email'])->send(new VerifyAlternative($data));
    return redirect()
        ->route('complaint.check')
        ->with('success', 'Register success. Please Check your email');
    }
      @endif
```

here's in my VerifyRequest

```
class VerifyRequest extends FormRequest
     {
                public function authorize()
        {
    return true;
   }
  public function rules()
     {
     return [
        'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('complaints')],
     ];
    }
    public function messages()
{
  return [
    'email.unique' => 'This email is making a Complaint. Wait for the complaint to be completed to make a complaint again' 
  ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation()
{ 
  
  $this->merge([
      'email' => $this->email . '@univesity.com',
  ]);
}
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this as soon as posible. Thank you in advanced

Comment: The result of `array_merge` will always be an array. You cannot call `->validated()` on an array.

Comment: i see, soo how can i make if the validation error it will also send a flash data (sweetalert) that i can show to my index page ?? Any suggestion

Comment: I don't really use Laravel so I'm not sure how the request validation logic works, but it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280524/check-if-validation-failed-in-laravel) you need to use a Validator to be able to use the `->fails()` method.